# How Do I Get `tree` to Selectively Exclude Contents of Directories?

Tags: filter, tree

I'm using `tree` on a directory which has -- among other things -- some Audacity projects in it.  Each Audacity project is some file `X.aup`, along side a directory `X_data`, which contains a few sub-directories, and dozens of `*.au` files.

What I'd like to do is have `tree` display the `X_data` folder, so I know it's there, but not descend into it.

I could omit the directory entirely with `tree -I '*_data' --matchdirs`, or I could omit what appears to be the only child directory of these `*_data`s: `tree -I 'e??' --matchdirs` (of course, that's likely to be too broad), but what I'd like to do is `tree -I '*_data/*'` (which doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you have to use tree?  find would probably be a better tool for this:

```
find audacity_projects -type f -name 'X.aup' -o -type d -name 'X_data'
```

Comment: I do want the structure of a tree output.  Also, your solution would *only* return the pair of things for the audacity project "X".

I'm looking for a normal tree output on a given directory, except that all *children* of any `*_data` directory are removed.